# How to trigger a MouseButton1Click event in Roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a button and I want to fire the event that happens when the player clicks on it by another script. I tried `button.MouseButton1Click()` but it didn't work. How can I achieve it?

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve? I smell a [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info). why not simply call the event listener?

Comment: @Piglet your "smellings" are wrong. We just want to fire the event that would run when a player clicks on a button here. If you just answered what was asked for, there would be a solution way earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse code, I would recommend looking into [ModuleScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/modulescripts). You can write your shared code functionality in the ModuleScript, and then use it in both places that you need it.

So in a ModuleScript in ReplicatedStorage, you might have something like :

```
local Foo = {}

function Foo.DoSomething()
    print("Doing the thing!")
    -- add your other behaviors here!
end

return Foo
```

Then, in your code with your button :

```
local Foo = require(game.ReplicatedStorage.Foo) -- put the path to your ModuleScript

local button = script.Parent
button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    Foo.DoSomething()
end)
```

And you can do the same thing in another script too!

```
local Foo = require(game.ReplicatedStorage.Foo)
Foo.DoSomething()
```

This way you won't have to fake a mouse click, your code simply exists in a sharable location.

Answer (score 0):

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()

mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function()
    print("Left mouse button was clicked")
end)
```

This code will print out "Left mouse button was clicked" whenever the left button is clicked.
But I didn't really get what you asked for.

Answer (score -1):

You need to connect the Click Event to a function:

```
button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
--whatever code you want to happen after the button is clicked goes here
end)
```